# Highlight text file at many lines

Tags: notepad++, text-editor

currently I have to review some text files (name them `source.txt` as example). And for each text file, i have a list of line numbers, saved in another text file (name them as `source_lines.txt`).

I want to have the lines, which are listed in `source_lines.txt`, highlighted in `source.txt` when I open it. The first idea is to use Style Token in notepad++, but then I have to enter each line one time and apply the style token, I don't know how to apply it at many lines automatically. Is there anyway to do that in notepad++, or some APIs from notepad++ that I can use in python to do that, or is there any other text editor which can do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is easy doable in the [CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com/) editor (open source) plugin. API allows to:

- read files using Python `text=open(filename).read()`
- make list of line numbers from this text
- add selections in the source.txt using `ed.set_caret()` API. You can add single caret or many carets, all carets with selections.
- or you can add bookmarks, using `ed.bookmark()` API
- handle the `on_open` event to activate your plugin